# setting focus on text-box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery accordion effect when the clicks on  a particular div the content of div appears ,i need the focus on a text-box inside the div?

Comment: Any textbox? Or do you know the textbox you wish to focus?

Comment: yeah there only one text box i have with the id="win"

Comment: @lalchand - updated. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the id of the text box, you could do the following:

```
$("#yourtextbox").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make use of the jQuery [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method:

```
$(div).click(function(){
  $(this).children("#win").focus();
});
```

Or if it's the only textbox with that ID (which it should be if you're using an ID), just call:

```
$("#win").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery function focus(), somthing like this:
(for first input field in a div without id)

```
<div id="myDiv" onclick="$('input', this).focus();">
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="">
</div>
```